# Laravel doesn't connect to database from web, but it does work from the CLI

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a quite unmodified new Laravel project, and I'm trying to get my first model up and running. I used `./vendor/bin/sail up` to run the webserver and MySQL with the default settings. I can access the database from DBeaver, the migrations run fine and I can even access my database data from the terminal using tinker:

```sh
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.12 (PHP 7.4.3 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> use App\Models\User;
>>> User::all()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4290
     all: [
       App\Models\User {#4292
         id: 1,
         name: "Johannes Molenaar",
         email: "gunes.dani@example.net",
         email_verified_at: "2022-01-10 13:51:35",
         #password: "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi",
         #remember_token: "bhuBvEAZ9c",
         created_at: "2022-01-10 13:51:35",
         updated_at: "2022-01-10 13:51:35",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Now when I try to do any of this in my `routes/web.php` file (or a controller for that matter), it does not work:

```php
Route::get('/', function() {
    App\Models\User::all();
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users`)

And it doesn't matter what model or ORM function I use, they all give me this same error. I checked my `.env` config, but I would think that an error in that config would also mean that artisan would be unable to access the database.

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tgi_laravel
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

config/database.php:

```php
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
    // sqlite, pgsql and sqlsrv here
],
```

Is there anybody who knows what could go wrong here? Let me know if there is any other information that is necessary to assess this problem.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm using php 8.1.1 in the web project, but Tinker seems to run on 7.4.3. Changing the php version of the server to 7.4.27 does not resolve this (changed docker image to `sail-7.4/app`).

Clearing the config cache does not work (`php artisan config:clear`).

Changing `DB_HOST` to `localhost` (instead of `127.0.0.1`) changes the error to 'No such file or directory'.

Comment: "I'm using php 8.1.1 in the web project, but Tinker seems to run on 7.4.3" How have you confirmed this? Why do you have 2 versions of PHP running on your server? By default, MySQL has networking disabled and you should be using localhost via sockets instead of 127.0.0.1. Have you confirmed the database is running, and have you configured PHP to use the appropriate socket file?

Comment: @miken32 Tinker metions it's version on startup (see my post) and I used `phpversion()` to spit out the version that the webserver is using. The difference came from Tinker running on my local php version while the webserver runs in a Docker container. It does not seem to make a difference anyway, as I added later.

Comment: Well obviously if your Laravel app is inside a docket container you have to run artisan commands from inside the container as well!

Comment: That still doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @miken32 You did give me a good hint there: running `php artisan tinker` from within the docker container did not work. That lead me to believe that MySQL was accessible from outside the container but not from within. This lead me to the final solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `DB_HOST` to `mysql` solved the issue.

The problem was that I was not able to reach the MySQL server from within the container, but I was able to reach it from outside of the container. This explains why DBeaver and Artisan Tinker (run from a commandline outside the container) were able to connect, but my Laravel server was not. Running `php artisan tinker` from withing the docker container (using `docker-compose exec laravel.test bash`) also didn't work.

I cloned a new Laravel project and spotted a difference in the .env configuration:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql             # Instead of 127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=example_app   # And this is a default that didn't
                          # contribute to the problem obviously
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score -1):

So maybe use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 on config file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Julien! Make sure to read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Your answer doesn't explain  how it solves the problem, and unfortunately it doesn't solve it at all either. The User model is loaded correctly and the error is somewhere in the database package or configuration if in the Laravel project at all.

Comment: Maybe my last sentence is the correct

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does a debug flag resolve a database problem?

Comment: It was just a suggest, I read too fast but maybe changing the connexion port of SQL can be the solution. Dont know. As said in my profile Im a beginner just trying to help

Comment: Fair enough, but Nico is right: edit your answer to remove redundant information and explain why changing the port might work. I tried it on another port, and sadly it did not work for me.

Comment: Dont know. Maybe tinker use a certain config and maybe laravel files use another.

Comment: Or maybe do DB_HOST=localhost and not 127.......

Comment: I actually started with `localhost`, but that gives me a different error: No such file or directory.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you're getting different errors between 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' indicates that the 127.0.0.1 is the correct connection string; it can't find localhost, but 127.0.0.1 isn't reliant on any lookups.

My guess would possibly be that the user 'sail' doesn't have proper permissions in the DB to access that table. I would go into MySQL / Maria, and GRANT ALL PERMISSIONS ON forge.* TO 'sail'@'localhost' and try again.

Also I'm not terribly familiar with sail, but a quick glance indicates besides "sail up" you may have to specify the DB, i.e. DB_DATABASE=forge.

Looking at your config file, the password for the user is blank. I assume you simply redacted it, but ensure that config file is correct on your dev instance!

Comment: I have given the sail user all permissions using this approach: https://gist.github.com/jjsquady/e12ce89c9029d520ce08f60a9ff8f304 (changed the user from laravel to sail). It does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: I did specify `DB_DATABASE` in my config and the password is not blank (but `password`), so that should also not be the problem.

Comment: `localhost` is not "reliant on any lookups," it uses a non-networked socket connection which is generally faster and safer; mysql by default has networking disabled so OP has likely messed with the configuration. A "connection refused" error does not point to an authentication or authorization problem, but rather a network one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to clear the config cache
**`php artisan config:clear`**
If clearing config does not work then you need to check if you have php driver for pdo or the connector you are using.

For example in pdo in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php*-mysql
```

where * is your active php version like 5.6, 7.4, 7.2, 8.1 etc
Restart your server i.e `sudo service apache2 restart` for apache

Comment: Like I said: "Clearing the config cache does not work (`php artisan config:clear`)." It's in the **EDIT** part of the original post.